# Confusing missing type specifier error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am getting a confusing `C4430 missing type specifier error` for all uses of `Vector4D`. I don't understand why it's being thrown. It's declared. It's defined. It exists. It is well-formed. (I commented out all uses and includes other than the class definition/declaration, the code compiled.) and it is included.

The code as-is works in VS2012 but not VS2010.

Here is a sample of the uses in the `Vector2D` class. There are similar for `Vector3D` including `Vector4D GetHomogeneous() const;` et. al.

```
#ifndef A2DE_CVECTOR2D_H
#define A2DE_CVECTOR2D_H

#include "../a2de_vals.h"
#include "CMiscMath.h"

#include "CVector3D.h"
#include "CVector4D.h"

A2DE_BEGIN

class Vector2D {

public:

    Vector2D();
    Vector2D(double x, double y);
    Vector2D(const Vector2D& vector);
    Vector2D(const Vector3D& v3d);
    Vector2D(const Vector4D& v4d);
    Vector2D(const Math::PolarCoordinate& magnitude_and_angle);
    ~Vector2D();
    double GetX() const;
    double GetX();
    double GetY() const;
    double GetY();
    double GetLength() const;
    double GetLength();
    double GetLengthSquared() const;
    double GetLengthSquared();
    double DotProduct(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    static double DotProduct(const Vector2D& a, const Vector2D& b);
    Vector2D Normalize() const;
    static void Normalize(Vector2D& v);
    Vector2D GetLeftNormal() const;
    Vector2D GetLeftNormal();
    Vector2D GetRightNormal() const;
    Vector2D GetRightNormal();
    Vector2D GetProjection(const Vector2D& b);
    static Vector2D GetProjection(const Vector2D& a, const Vector2D& b);
    Vector2D GetProjectionOnXAxis();
    Vector2D GetProjectionOnYAxis();
    double GetAngle() const;
    double GetAngle();
    static double GetAngle(const Vector2D& v);
    double GetAngleFrom(const Vector2D& b);
    static double GetAngleFrom(const Vector2D& b, const Vector2D& a);
    static double GetFacingAngle(const Vector2D& target, const Vector2D& source);
    static Vector2D GetFacingVector(const Vector2D& target, const Vector2D& source);
    Vector2D& operator=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator=(const Vector3D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator=(const Vector4D& rhs);
    bool operator==(const Vector2D& rhs);
    bool operator==(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    bool operator!=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    bool operator!=(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    Vector2D& operator+=(double scalar);
    Vector2D& operator-=(double scalar);
    Vector2D& operator*=(double scalar);
    Vector2D& operator/=(double scalar);
    Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D operator-(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    Vector2D operator-(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D operator-();
    Vector2D operator*(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    Vector2D operator*(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D operator/(const Vector2D& rhs) const;
    Vector2D operator/(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator+=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator-=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator*=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator/=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    operator Vector3D();
    operator Vector4D();
    Vector3D GetHomogeneous() const;
    Vector3D GetHomogeneous();
    friend Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D& v_lhs, double scalar_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator+(double scalar_lhs, const Vector2D& v_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator-(const Vector2D& v_lhs, double scalar_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator-(double scalar_lhs, const Vector2D& v_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator*(const Vector2D& v_lhs, double scalar_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator*(double scalar_lhs, const Vector2D& v_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator/(const Vector2D& v_lhs, double scalar_rhs);
    friend Vector2D operator/(double scalar_lhs, const Vector2D& v_rhs);

protected:

    void SetX(double x);
    void SetY(double y);
    void SetTerminal(double x, double y);

    double _x;
    double _y;
    double _angle;

private:
};


A2DE_END

#endif
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us the Vector4D definition if that's throwing errors, and code using it. (Or do you say that the code you presented doesn't compile?)

Comment: I didn't see that Vector4D is actually referenced in the code presented, e.g. in ` Vector2D& operator=(const Vector4D& rhs);`. Does that line not compile? I'd still like to see the CVector4D.h file. Just to ask: The class declared in **C**Vector4D.h is called Vector4D.h, right? The header is being found? No namespaces?

Comment: There is a bad smell of circular dependency here... You should use some forward declaration, like `class Vector4D;` in your header file, instead of the includes.

Comment: @Vince That was it. Can't believe I overlooked it... Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including similar types in header files is leading me to think you may have circular dependencies. It is recommended to use forward declarations in headers, and it appears from your `Vector2D` definition that instead of the `#includes`, you can simply use:

```
class Vector3D;
class Vector4D;
```

Comment: I had been (improperly) following the advice of Meyer that if the declaration contains only pointer or reference types in the declaration that I use forward declarations. All other cases must include the whole file. Apparently mixed-types (pointer/reference and non-pointer/reference) fall under this rule as well.